# Histogram problems in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to take means of random samples from a randomly generated population and plot it on a histogram. However, I get very weird shapes. I am looking for a normally shaped histogram. But this is what I get: What might be the reason?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dbplyr)
library(plyr)
set.seed(1234)
Pop_mean <- 100
Pop_SD <- 15
population <-  rnorm(5000, Pop_mean, Pop_SD)
population <- data.frame(population)

#sampling
##sample size
n = 100
#number of samples
N = 1000
#create empty vector of length n 
sample_means = rep(NA, N) 
#take a random sample from the population 

#fill empty vector with means
for (i in 1:N){
  sample <- sample(population$population, size = n, replace = T)
  sample_means[i] <-  mean(sample)
}

sample_means <- data.frame(sample_means)
summary(sample_means)
#sample means histogram
ggplot(sample_means, aes (x=sample_means))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  ylim (c (0,300)) + xlim (c(80,120))
```

Comment: `xlim` and `ylim` remove data from your plot that lies outside those limits - if you use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,300), xlim =c(80,120))` instead, you keep all data and only limit the range that is shown. This even has a special section in the [ggplot2 cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) (Zooming with/without clipping)

Comment: Also, noting that `range(sample_means)` returns `[1]  95.71404 105.24278`, your bin width is too large, try `binwidth = 1`. With the default `bins=30`, `diff(range(sample_means))/30` gives a bin width of 0.32, so a number like 0.5 could also be used.

Comment: The problem seems to be the bins one! Thank you very much. This seems too obvious and trivial now, but I couldn't see it myself.